# IPv6 Subnet Delegation

Tags: networking, cisco, ipv6, subnet

I'm a bit confused on how to calculate IPv6 numbering. I have a /32 now and a VPN client that wants 6 x /48 from that /32. Could someone please simplify on how I can determine the points of the /32 for the request? I tried a subnet calculator online but not quite getting a grip on this. IPv4 is a piece of cake compared to numbering IPv6.

Thanks.

Comment: Really, you just aren't used to it. IPv6 addressing is much easier than IPv4 addressing. The size of the addresses mess with people's heads, but having a single subnet size makes things easy.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to delegate individual /48s.  Assuming your /32 is  `2001:DB8::/32` your zone is `8.b.d.0.1.0.0.2.ip6.arpa`.  Reverse zones are done by dotted nibbles. That is why recommended sub-delegations are a `/56` or a `/48`.  This yields 256, and 65356 /64 subnets respectively.

If you assign 6 zones starting with `2001:DB8:1234/48`, you would need to delegate the relative addresses `4.3.2.1` through `9.3.2.1`

It appears your clients are requesting the capability to create 393216 subnets.  Each network segment requires a /64 subnet.  Each device will have one or more /128 addresses.  Normally a device on the network segment (usually the router) will announce the applicable /64 subnet.  In place of DHCP, devices can self-configure based on the announced subnet.  It is still possible to assign fixed IPv6 addresses for devices such as servers, routers, and printers.  Each /64 subnet has about 2^64 (18,446,744,073,709,551,616) addresses available for devices.